# Phone Number List "Error C2059 syntax error: ']'"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing an assignment for school and can't get past this error.
I'm getting an syntax error in my code stating on line 28 expected an expression before ']'. Thank you for your time.   Edit: It now compiles but it doesn't find a display the name when entered.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string searcharray(string [], string);
int main()
{
    string Phone_Numbers[] = { "Becky Warren, 555-1223" "Joe   Looney,      555-0097" "Geri Palmer, 555-8787"
    "Lynn Presnell, 555-1212" "Holly Gaddis, 555-8878" "Sam Wiggins,     555-0998"
    "Bob Kain, 555-8712" "Tim Haynes, 555-7676" "Warren Gaddis,  555-9037" "Jean James, 555-4939"
    "Ron Palmer, 555-2783" };
string Name, found;

  cout << "Please enter a name to display the phone number: ";
  getline(cin, Name);

  found = searcharray(Phone_Numbers, Name);

cout << "We found this Phone number listed with the name you entered:  \n";
cout << found;

return 0;
}

string searcharray(string *Phone_Numbers, string Name)
{
string found;
found = Phone_Numbers[]->find(Name);

return found;
}
```

Comment: Line#28, try changing to `found = Phone_Numbers->find(Name);`

Comment: This program doesn't work as you intend it to. Better consider std::map

Comment: You are correct after fixing the syntax issue It runs but when a name is entered nothing is shown. We have not learned map yet so I'm not sure how to use. I did a read up on it but I'm not sure I'm allowed to use it.

Comment: yes, because your string is a flat list and searcharray doesn't do much in parsing the string. If you are not allowed to use std::map, then perhaps `searcharray` must do string parsing based on delimiters like `,` as used in Phone_Numbers initializer_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Array to pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_to_pointer_decay) for more understanding of the implicit conversion rules.

```
// C++ will implicitly convert parameter Phone_Numbers[] to *Phone_Numbers
string searcharray(string Phone_Numbers[], string Name)
{
string found;
found = Phone_Numbers->find(Name); // operator -> must be used 

return found;
}
```

This means C++ implicitly converts parameters using the array syntax ([]) to the pointer syntax (*). That means the following two function declarations are identical:

> ```
> 1.  string searcharray(string Phone_Numbers[], string Name)
>
> 2.  string searcharray(string *Phone_Numbers, string Name)
> ```

Here is sample program using std::map

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

string searcharray(map<string, string>, string);
int main()
{
    map<string, string>  Phone_Numbers= { 
            {"Becky Warren", "555-1223"}, 
            {"Joe Looney", "555-0097"},
            {"Geri Palmer", "555-8787"}
          };
string Name, found;

  cout << "Please enter a name to display the phone number: ";
  getline(cin, Name);

  found = searcharray(Phone_Numbers, Name);

cout << "We found this Phone number listed with the name you entered:  \n";
cout << found;

return 0;
}

string searcharray(map<string, string> Phone_Numbers, string Name)
{
  string phoneNumber;
  if(Phone_Numbers.find(Name) != Phone_Numbers.end())
  {
    phoneNumber = Phone_Numbers[Name]; 
  }
  return phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After fixing that issue it now compiles but not running as intended. When a name is searched nothing is found and displayed with that name.

Comment: @skididdy: Your code isn't correct because the `Phone_Numbers` array only contains a single entry. You forgot to put a comma between each of the elements in your initialization list. Then you'll have to rewrite your code to actually search an array. Read your textbook again...